# How are privacy policies done?

Tags: android, string, hyperlink

I am curious about the proper way of doing privacy policies if displaying natively in a mobile app? I can create a string constant, however, it seems like it would be easier to add as a text file and then read from the text file. This is what I wanted to do, however, the text that should be hyperlinked would not be hyperlinked.

```
private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("config.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

So how is everyone doing this?

Comment: I do mine from text files, they don't contain hyperlinks within text though (I add the hyperlinks dynamically at the end or beginning of my privacy policy after/before I add my text file stuff. If you want to do it it this way you can load it through a StringBuilder, build the string, and then parse it out, searching for `http*`. Not that this is necessarily the best way of doing it, but it is an option off the top of my head.

Comment: I think I get what you are doing. I can see that working, but not I need recursive scripts to comb through the text searching for hyperlinks, and then setting them as hyperlinks. I am not certain if that is any easier than just creating a string constant. But thank you for the suggestion, I had not thought of this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you plan on your policy changing you'd want to pull it off a database or something.

Comment: Aye, I am anticipating that it will change. So I was thinking along the same lines as you. Ok, thank you for the suggestion. +1 for answer